# On save, can I automatically build an exploded war with maven in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, save, war, exploded

I am working on few projects that use maven for dependency management and deployment. Is there a way for me to have eclipse keep an exploded war file (based on the deployment structure defined in the pom.xml) up to date with the changes I am making in real time and then run that exploded war on my local tomcat server (also from eclipse)?

I know how to do a run as > maven build > goals: package war:exploded. This gives me the folder I am looking for. But I want it to happen every time I save a file (like eclipse's build automatically feature). I have been struggling for days trying to figure this out and it is driving me crazy >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin I was looking for is here: eclipse.org/m2e-wtp

Comment: any example configuration ?

Comment: Downvoted. Sorry but the answer doesn't help much if you don't already know it. No configuration, link, details etc.

Answer (score -1):

It's a combination of the right project facets and most importantly the m2e plugin